# Controlling what files to display

Tags: ls

I recently changed my emacs config to hide backup files by prepending a dot to the file name. This got me to thinking - is there a ready way to change the behavior within Bash to use a list of arbitrary globs for what files to hide? A quick scan of the bash and ls man pages didn't turn up anything.

Comment: You mean, e.g. have `ls` ignore all files that start with `ignore-` or all files that end in `.bak`?

Comment: Yes, preferably with the ability to do wildcard pattern matching as well, ignore-*.bak, etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls` has a `--hide=PATTERN` option that looks like it does what you want and can be overridden to show  them with `-a` or `-A`.  If you want this to happen automatically, add an alias in your `~/.bashrc` (or, in the likely case that there is already an alias for it, add it to that alias).

```
$ touch {a,b,c}-{1,2,3}
$ ls
a-1  a-2  a-3  b-1  b-2  b-3  c-1  c-2  c-3
$ ls --hide=a*
b-1  b-2  b-3  c-1  c-2  c-3
$ ls --hide=*1
a-2  a-3  b-2  b-3  c-2  c-3
$ ls --hide=a*1
a-2  a-3  b-1  b-2  b-3  c-1  c-2  c-3
$ ls --hide=a*1 -A
a-1  a-2  a-3  b-1  b-2  b-3  c-1  c-2  c-3
```

There is also an `--ignore=PATTERN` that isn't overridden by the `-a` and `-A` options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just one question: why doesn't `ls --hide=*1 a*` not hide anything, but still lists all three `a-1  a-2  a-3`? I would have expected it to hide the `a-1`?

Comment: The `a*` is expanded by the shell and includes `a-1`. The hide option doesn't ignore files explicitly named as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alias for `ls`:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto --hide='*~' --hide='#*#'"
```

That hides files like `backup.c~` and `#autosave.h#`. (And, opinionated as I am, I like colors, so it does that too.)