# syntax of ls --hide= and ls --ignore=

Tags: linux, command-line, regular-expression, ls, options

`ls --hide` and `ls --ignore` provides the possibility leave out files defined through regular expressions set after the `--ignore=` part. The latter makes sure that this option isn't turned off via `-a, -A`. The command's `man` and `info` page mention Regular Expressions.

**Question**: Which wildcards or Regular Expressions are supported in `ls --hide=` and `ls --ignore=`.

I found out that `* $ ?` seem to be supported, as well as POSIX Bracket Expressions. But this doesn't seem to work properly all the time and is more a game of trial and error for me. Did I miss something important here?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26900/controlling-what-files-to-display

Comment: Somewhat related, but this question is specifically about `--ignore` whereas the question you cited is about emacs and `--ignore` is only mentioned in passing in the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Which-files-are-listed):

> `-I pattern`, `--ignore=pattern`
>
> In directories, ignore files whose names match the shell pattern (not regular expression) pattern. As in the shell, an initial `.` in a file name does not match a wildcard at the start of pattern. Sometimes it is useful to give this option several times. For example,
>
> ```
>      $ ls --ignore='.??*' --ignore='.[^.]' --ignore='#*'
> ```
>
> The first option ignores names of length 3 or more that start with `.`, the second ignores all two-character names that start with `.` except `..`, and the third ignores names that start with `#`.

You can use only shell [glob patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)): `*` matches any number of characters, `?` matches any one character, `[…]` matches the characters within the brackets and `\` quotes the next character. The character `$` stands for itself (make sure it's within single quotes or preceded by a `\` to protect it from shell expansion).

Answer (score 0):

It uses POSIX.2 regex pattern format. **See the `re_format(7)` man page** for specific details.

Comment: this is what I meant with POSIX Bracket Expression, exactly :)

Comment: I guess what I really meant was to tell you to just read the man page.